# Is it possible to make an existing string editable for the user using Scanner? If so, how?

Tags: java, string, input, java.util.scanner

My program has `String A = "hello";` and I want it to paste "A" into the user's input space so the user can modify it (e.g. backspace, add more text). Then once the user is done, they can just press enter and their input overwrites "A".

This what I've tried, but it can only add text, not delete them:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner ir = new Scanner (System.in);
        String A = "Hello";
        System.out.println(A);
        A = A+ ir.nextLine();
        System.out.println(A);
    }
}
```

and this is the output:

```java
Hello // output
 There  // input
Hello There // output
```

When I try to use backspace, it doesn't remove any characters from "Hello".

Comment: Not possible, I’m afraid.  Output and input are completely separate from each other.  Program output cannot be “undone.”  What is your goal?  Perhaps there is another way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking, you can use String Builder. Initiate it while making an Object, and take user input in B. At last use String Builder's append function to merge both outputs.

Like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in)) {
            String A = "Hello";
            StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder(A);
            System.out.println(A); // Current Value of A
            String B = input.nextLine(); // Taking User's input
            newStr = newStr.append(B); // Changing A's Value
            System.out.println(newStr); // New value
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello // A's default Value
 There // Input value with blank space
Hello There // Final Output with String Builder
```